# Using NodaTime, how to convert an Instant to the corresponding system's ZonedDateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I have an event log in a database with the events' datetime stored as UTC time. In my application, where I'm using NodaTime, I get the value as a `DateTime` and then convert it to an `Instant`:

```
var instant = NodaTime.Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(eventDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

Now I want to get the `ZonedDateTime` corresponding to `instant` using the system's time zone. I know I can use `instant.InZone(systemTimeZone)` to get the `ZonedDateTime` I need. However, I don't know how to populate the `systemTimeZone` variable with the correct value. How can I get the `DateTimeZone` object corresponding to the system's time zone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`IDateTimeZoneProvider.GetSystemDefault`](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/html/T_NodaTime_IDateTimeZoneProvider.htm) for the time zone provider you're interested in. For example:

```
var systemZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
var zonedDateTime = instant.InZone(systemZone);
```

Or use `DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl` to use the appropriate `TimeZoneInfo`-backed time zone.